# Slowing down playback for realtime animation

Tags: animation, animation-nodes, blend-files

So recently I have been looking into real time animating. More specifically VR animating and while I was looking I found this program called Tvori which allows you to basically just grab the object and move it while it's playing. It's not new technology but they have this time feature that isn't in blender. It basically allows you to slow down the play back speed so you can more accurately make the object react better with the scene.

here's the video: https://youtu.be/-PFIfU43H28?t=122

I tried to attempt this in blender with the time remap tool but it's not accurate. It will create the keyframes but it will create them further down the timeline with inaccuracy. I tried to move it but it doesn't work.

I was wondering if there was anyway to slow down the timeline without using the timemap tool. Maybe have something just like the time map tool but it would allow people to perform realtime animations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want is to adjust the frame rate. Use a higher frame rate for your animations (e.x. 120), and when you want to slow down and animate something else, simply lower the frame rate and animate that.
I've recorded a video to better demonstrate the concept
https://youtu.be/dlqBWrtDHcM

Comment: Thank you! This works amazingly!!